# Open and save xml file from jmeter command line

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to manipulate jmeter test plan in a web based tool. The problem is, it converts many characters to implicitly. For example `&quot;`  converts to `"`, `&#xd;` converts to newline.

I  observed that, if i open that modified file from jmeter ui and save it without doing anything, all the characters are converted back to original. For example `"` converts to `&quot;`.

So is it possible to do this automatically using jquery/javascript. I am using angularjs with node.js for my application. I would prefer to do this open-save-close operation in background. Please suggest , how can i achieve this. is there any jmeter-plugin available which i can run from javascript/jquery ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Jmeter is doing correct thing. e.g if value contains >(greater than), then it is a special character as it's part of tags. So these values are stored as converted character, and then when read back, they are converted to original chars..

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the following characters in XML, otherwise it will result into invalid markup.

```
"
'
<
>
&
```

Given you use [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) you can use [xml-escape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-escape) function to do the trick for you.

JMeter provides [__escapeXML()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__escapeXml) function out of the box just in case you're looking for Java-based implementation, see [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.

Answer (score 0):

What jmeter is doing with XML is correct and is done by the library XStream.

JMeter manipulate Java Objects and serializes them using [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/).

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I don't think it is correct in terms of maintainability, indeed JMeter doesn't provide any contract on XML (XSD or DTD). Test plans should be manipulated through Java.

As far as I know, you cannot manipulate it through javascript, but you can potentially use this DSL to manipulate/generate test plans:

- https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter